How to prevent view from being pushed upward and avoid scroll when mobile keyboard opens in Next.js?
I'm building a chat interface in a Next.js application and using Tailwind CSS for styling. I'm detecting when the mobile keyboard is open using a custom hook (useMobileKeyboardStatus). However, when the keyboard opens, the entire view is pushed upwards, creating an unwanted scroll. This causes the input field to sometimes hide when scrolling.
I want the view to resize so that the top of the window stays put, without any scroll, and the input field floats above the keyboard. How can I achieve this behavior in Next.js?
Here is a simplified version of my layout:
"use client";
import useMobileKeyboardStatus from "@/hooks/useMobileKeyboardStatus";
import "./globals.css";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

export default function RootLayout() {
  const isKeyboardOpen = useMobileKeyboardStatus();
  return (
<html lang="en">
  <body className="bg-black ">
    <div class="w-full md:w-custom mx-auto  ">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div class="w-full  bg-[#0A0B0D] mx-auto relative">
              <header class="flex items-center justify-center mt-6 mx-4 mb-4 gap-4">
                <span class="text-white font-semibold text-base">
                  Assistant
                </span>
              </header>
              <div class=" ">
                <div class="flex gap-4 items-center mb-6">
                  <div>
                    <h1 class="text-xl mb-1">Assistant</h1>
                    <p class="text-[#878C99]">Your AI Assistant</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="px-2 pt-2 fixed bottom-[0px] w-full">
              {isKeyboardOpen ? "keyboard open" : "keyboard close"}
              <div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Message" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
  );
}

How can I modify the layout or styles to prevent the entire view from being pushed upwards and avoid the scroll when the keyboard is open? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
